# How to receive TCP data while the iPod is in hibernation mode?

Tags: objective-c

I want to constantly send data to the iPod.  But how can I do this when the iPod is in hibernation mode?  If I disable the hibernation mode, then the batteries will be used up in the matter of hours.

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't.  The whole point of hibernation mode is to totally limit battery consumption in all ways and that includes turning off the WiFi radio.

What you can do is minimize power consumption;  turn off the screen, use minimal CPU, etc...

However, I'm not versed in the ways of the APIs to know specifically what is possible.